# Does "SELECT...WHERE 1" stop MySQL using an index?

Tags: mysql, indexing

MySQL/MariaDB has `log_queries_not_using_indexes` enabled and this query shows in the log:

```
SELECT * FROM `client` WHERE 1 ORDER BY `code` ASC;
```

The `client` table has a `BTREE` index defined with the `code` column. I'm curious why it wasn't used. I understand [indexes can still be used with simple ordering](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11031/order-by-column-should-have-index-or-not).

Is the index not used because of the `WHERE 1` clause in the query? Or is using an index simply not necessary with a simple query like that?

This is academic for me, the query runs fast already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`log_queries_not_using_indexes` is, in my opinion, useless.  If a query is slow enough to matter, it will show up in the slowlog without this setting.  And the setting just clutters the slowlog.

`WHERE 1` is equivalent to not having a `WHERE` clause.

The Optimizer will *consider* using `INDEX(code)`, if you have such, so that it can avoid a sort pass.  But...

Plan A:  Use such an index, but have to bounce back and forth between the index's BTree and the data's BTree.

Plan B:  Ignore the index, but have to do a sort.  (The "sort" may or may not be done in memory.  For example, a `TEXT` column will prevent sorting in RAM.)

The Optimizer makes a crude estimate about which would be more efficient.  That is, it may deliberately decide not to use an index, thereby leading to the "noise" in the slowlog.  I repeat, turn off that flag.

Comment: `log_queries_not_using_indexes` was successful in my scenario and I didn't mind the noise (if anything it led me to this answer, thanks!) I'll consider both next time, I suppose each has its uses

Answer (score 1):

No, it has nothing to do with `WHERE 1`. It is to do with the fact that retrieving all rows row-by-row after traversing the btree index on code is likely to be slower than reading the whole lot into memory and doing a sort.